# Fancybox - Can't Set CSS with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fancybox

I was trying to adjust the position of my Fancybox with jQuery:

```
$('#fancybox-wrap').css("top", "200px !important");
```

And it wasn't working at all even with the **!important** bit. However if I simply do it with CSS, it's an OK deal:

```
#fancybox-wrap {
    top: 200px !important;
}
```

Which leaves me really curious: is there something inside Fancybox' codes that's preventing me from changing the wrapper's CSS via JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

The css function put styles in `style` attribute. Some navigators seem to not allow usage of `!important` in inline style. But inline style should overpass css rule even if it is "important". So

```
$('#fancybox-wrap').css("top", "200px");
```

should work?

Comment: It's not working. The problem is not with the !important part it would seem.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle or a link?

Answer (score 0):

May be not a nice way but you can go this:

```
cssString = $('#fancybox-wrap').attr("style");
cssString = cssString.replace("top: 200px", "top: 200px !important");
$('#fancybox-wrap').removeAttr("style").attr("style", cssString);
```

Comment: This probably would work, but I guess I'll simply use CSS than doing this... lol

Comment: how can you be sure that it is stored as "top: 200px" and not "top:200px" ?

Comment: @basZero The associated method -ultimately the browser- won't modify the string. And even if so, it doesn't matter. When the browser invokes the new style attribute, he will correct the values to a suiteable argument list for himself. That means that 'top: 200px;' is identical to 'top:200px;'.